# Dragging a rotated and absolute positioned div with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-draggable, css-transforms

When I try to drag an absolute positioned and rotated div ( with css3 `transform: rotate(45deg)`) using jQuery UI draggable, it seems that jQuery doesn't know where the new origin of the rotated div is.
Therefore, when you start dragging, the div is instantly moved a few pixels away.

Here is a jsFiddle so you can see for yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/k7g7R/4/
(rotate the div by clicking on it and then drag it).

Note that it works just fine when the draggable div is in relative position.

Does anyone know what's happening, and how I can fix this?

Comment: please be more clear in explaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably relates to jQuery offset() which is wrong after css3 transforms:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6844

The way I would fix this is by putting a wrapper around the object you are rotating, and make that wrapper draggable.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="object" style="left: 90px; top: 90px;">Click to rotate, and drag</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See your updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/k7g7R/128/
(updated link because jQueryRotate was missing)